# split a large text into a variable number of parts

Tags: php, arrays

```
$x = 4;
$story = "BUT I MUST EXPLAIN TO YOU HOW ALL THIS MISTAKEN IDEA OF DENOUNCING PLEASURE AND PRAISING PAIN WAS BORN AND I WILL GIVE YOU A COMPLETE ACCOUNT OF THE SYSTEM AND EXPOUND THE ACTUAL TEACHINGS OF THE GREAT EXPLORER";
```

I need something like this:

```
$arr = explode(' 'nth($x), $story);
```

For example if `$x == 4` each element wil contain four words:

`BUT I MUST EXPLAIN
TO YOU HOW ALL
etc`

If `$x == 5` each element wil contain five words:

`BUT I MUST EXPLAIN TO
YOU HOW ALL THIS MISTAKEN
etc`

Any idea?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: One approach would be to count the whitespaces between the words and split the string after $x-1 whitespaces. But that's just a rough idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array_chunk()` to do this:

```
<?php
    $x = 4;
    $story = "BUT I MUST EXPLAIN TO YOU HOW ALL THIS MISTAKEN IDEA OF DENOUNCING PLEASURE AND PRAISING PAIN WAS BORN AND I WILL GIVE YOU A COMPLETE ACCOUNT OF THE SYSTEM AND EXPOUND THE ACTUAL TEACHINGS OF THE GREAT EXPLORER";

    # we do a normal explode to get it into an array
    $arr = explode(' ', $story);
    # break into arrays divided by $x
    echo '<pre>'. print_r(array_chunk($arr, $x), 1) .'</pre>';
```

Then you can you loop the `array_chunk` array and echo out - or `implode()` using line breaks.

refs:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$story = "BUT I MUST EXPLAIN TO YOU HOW ALL THIS MISTAKEN IDEA OF DENOUNCING PLEASURE AND PRAISING PAIN WAS BORN AND I WILL GIVE YOU A COMPLETE ACCOUNT OF THE SYSTEM AND EXPOUND THE ACTUAL TEACHINGS OF THE GREAT EXPLORER";

foreach(
    array_chunk(
        str_word_count($story, 1),
        4 // Your chunk size.
    ) as $group
)
    echo implode(' ', $group), "\n";
```

Output:

```
BUT I MUST EXPLAIN
TO YOU HOW ALL
THIS MISTAKEN IDEA OF
DENOUNCING PLEASURE AND PRAISING
PAIN WAS BORN AND
I WILL GIVE YOU
A COMPLETE ACCOUNT OF
THE SYSTEM AND EXPOUND
THE ACTUAL TEACHINGS OF
THE GREAT EXPLORER
```